# What happened to Newton 3rd law if our Moon is moving away at 1.5" yearly?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, solar-system, tidal-effect, moon

Our Moon is going away and I read that it is the culprit is our ocean, but then what happens to Newton 3rd law there should be an equal and opposite forces too so where's that? Is it absorbed by the ocean if so in what kind of form?

Comment: Newton's law is entirely unaffected by what the moon does or doesn't do. It's the other way around: The moon is governed by Newton's laws

Comment: Nothing “happens” to the third law. The equal and opposite gravitational force between the Earth and moon decreases, but infinitesimally annually

Answer (score 1):

Both the moon and the earth are affected by the force of gravitation of one another with the same magnitude according to Newton's third law. What matters here is the tidal forces (the fact that the gravitational force is not acting identically everywhere). For a clear explanation see this video from PBS space-time: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwChk4S99i4.

In the end these tidal force act as a friction that get dissipated as heat and make the system earth/moon loose energy and angular momentum, explaining why the moon is getting further away.

**Edit: The total angular momentum must be conserved and simply transferred from the earth slowing down to the moon. See comments below.**

Comment: If the moon looses angular momentum, then I expect it gets closer.. how to understand the "sign" of the displacement?

Comment: I was talking about the full system system moon/earth.  Individually, the moon is gaining angular momentum, explaining why it gets further away, while the earth loosed angular momentum (its rotation on itself is slowing down).

Comment: Thank you, still I find it counterintuitive that the moon gains angular momentum and I was wondering if there is an intuitive explanation. Anyway, nice answer!

Comment: Thanks! I agree that this can be quite counterintuitive at first. You can find some nicer explanations than I could ever give on this thread on this thread of the space stack exchange: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/why-is-momentum-transferred-to-the-moon

Comment: The system doesn't lose angular momentum. There's just an exchange between Earth and Moon.

Comment: Well some of the energy/angular momentum must be dissipated by the tidal forces at some level, shouldn't it?

Comment: LéoVacher evergy yes, it is "dissipated" (you heat up a bit the ocean) but angular momentum is strictly conserved even in the presence of friction/dissipation, so it must be an exchange between Earth and Moon, as @Sten suggests.

Comment: My bad! let me edit the answer then!